# How to write a test case for a simple React component using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a simple React component which looks like something as shown below:

```
export default class New_Component {
   static propTypes = {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        mobile: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        address: PropTypes.string.isRequired
   };
}

render() {
   return(
    <div>
      <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
      <h6>{this.props.mobile}</h6>
      <p>{this.props.address}</p>
   </div>
 )
}
```

So,if I want to write a test case for the above component using **Jest** and **Enzyme**, what are the possible test cases that can be written for this component? Can someone please guide me? I am not able to figure out what are the possible test cases as I do not have any functions in this component so that I can check for the result of the function in an **expect()** function.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials that extensively cover testing react components. Take a look at [snapshot testing](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html). This is usually a good idea for pure presentational components. Other then that there is just not much to test on your component. You do not have to write tests for every trivial component.

Comment: @trixn actually I was asked to write a test case on the component.So, I was just wondering where to apply and how to start. Could you please help me write at least a single test case on this component.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Show us at least an attempted solution and we can help you to fix the concrete issues of your code. [To get started you can e.g. read this](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/testing-your-react-component-with-jest-and-enzyme-276eef45bea0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is ok not to write any unit test for that simple component and focus your short time on this earth writing end to end tests for example.

If your manager is monitoring the % coverage of test in your app, you can simply test that your component renders the `name`, `mobile` and `address`:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<New_Component
  name="testName"
  mobile="000000"
  address="addressMobile"
/>);

expect(wrapper.find('h1').text()).to.equal('testName');
expect(wrapper.find('h6').text()).to.equal('000000');
expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).to.equal('addressMobile');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example. i will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

As I've just recently jumped into the React world I'll give you a sample to get started with. Testing can be a daunting task.

HOWEVER I agree with the accepted answer in that this might be overkill for a component of this size.

This would be my starting point for something that may become more complex.

```
describe("<New_Component/>", () => {
  let actual;

  const complete_props = {
    name: "test",
    mobile: 12345678,
    address: "123 test road"
  };



 describe("given all neccessary props", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      actual = shallow(<NewComponent {...complete_props} />);
    });

    it("renders correctly", () => {
      expect(actual).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it("should render the component", () => {
      expect(actual.find("NewComponent"));
    });

    it("should render three children", () => {
      expect(actual.children().length).toEqual(3);
    });

    it("should render h1 with correct prop", () => {
      expect(actual.props().children[0]).toEqual(
        <h1>{complete_props.name}</h1>
      );
    });

    it("should render h6 with correct prop", () => {
      expect(actual.props().children[1]).toEqual(
        <h6>{complete_props.mobile}</h6>
      );
    });

    it("should render p with correct prop", () => {
      expect(actual.props().children[2]).toEqual(
        <p>{complete_props.address}</p>
      );
    });
  });
});
```

In the future you should at least attempt a solution solution before asking for help. The community here is far more giving with their time if they see you've made some effort yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I totally agree with you.Actually I was going through some examples which had some functions and the test was written based on the functions. So I was not able to figure out how to proceed with such a component and just wanted a little guidance on how to proceed.Anyways thanks again for the suggestion and the answer.From next time on, I will try to implement something on my own and then ask for help . :)